# Do stockholders ever get money from a chapter 7 bankruptcy?

Tags: united-states, stocks, bankruptcy

And if they do, does it occur with any frequency that you could calculate the possible (non-zero) worth of your stocks if such an event were to occur?

Comment: I've heard rumors that people might buy (for very little) the stock of a bankrupt company so that it can be used as a [shell corporation](http://www.finra.org/investors/alerts/dormant-shell-companies-portfolio-fraud).  Though these are often associated with fraud, they may be a legitimate way to gain access to capital markets.  [Here's another site that sells public shell companies](https://www.mergernetwork.com/public-shell-companies-for-sale/page-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically if the company is so out of whack that it's liquidating, it won't have assets to even cover all its debts never mind enough to return anything back to owners.  If there was any shot of the company continuing as an ongoing concern it would file an 11 and reorganize.